# Google maps API additional events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

Is there any event in Google maps API,

which gets fired when I drag and drop an external object on anywhere on the Google map , so that I can get the latitude and longitude of the dragged object?
I want this to be done using pure Javascript itself without any library being used.

I have gone through all the events from the documentation, none of the events get fired when an external object is dropped on to it.

Comment: What kind of *external object*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a draggable marker? Could you use "mouseout"?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {

 //do your stuff here

});
```

Comment: No its not a marker at all . The object/image is not present in the map , it is outside .

Comment: Ah ok. I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/rewAUM00A5A
Hopefully it will help you.